# can't find error with code - trying to print name of parent directory

Tags: java, io

Like the title, I'm trying to print the name of my current directory and parent directory and print all the files and directories of each. The code works fine with the current directory.

But when I try to print the name of the parent directory, it somehow is just blank.

The following is my code.

```
import java.io.*;

class IOTest2
{
    public static void printList(File[] list)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(list[i].getName());
            if(list[i].isDirectory())
                System.out.println("\t \t DIR");
            else
                System.out.println("\t \t FILE");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File currentDir = new File(workingDir);
        System.out.println("current dir: " + currentDir.getName());
        File[] curList = currentDir.listFiles();
        printList(curList);

        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        File parentDir = currentDir.getParentFile();
        System.out.println("parent dir: " + parentDir.getName());
        File[] parList = parentDir.listFiles();
        printList(parList);
    }
}
```

And the following is the result I get in the console regarding the parent directory.(the current directory works fine so I didn't include it here)
As you can see, it is blank after "parent dir: "

```
parent dir:
$Recycle.Bin             DIR
book             DIR
bootmgr          FILE
BOOTNXT          FILE
Config.Msi               DIR
Documents and Settings           DIR
gpki             DIR
hiberfil.sys             FILE
Intel            DIR
Irvine           DIR
JavaStudy                DIR
MATS             DIR
MSOCache                 DIR
myclass          DIR
MyJava           DIR
NaverGame                DIR
Nexon            DIR
pagefile.sys             FILE
PerfLogs                 DIR
PhoneBookVer3_duplicate class error              DIR
Program Files            DIR
Program Files (x86)              DIR
ProgramData              DIR
Recovery                 DIR
swapfile.sys             FILE
System Volume Information                DIR
Temp             DIR
Users            DIR
Windows          DIR
XecureSSL                DIR
YourJava                 DIR

C:\JavaStudy>
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: "C:\" is not a name of directory, it's the *drive*. The parent directory name of "C:\JavaStudy" is indeed blank.

Comment: oh!! i didn't know that thank you! I think I expected there to be a C or sth..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current directory is `C:\JavaStudy`, but since `C:` is the DRIVE, it doesn't print out (as expected) a `C:\` file path. If you want the String `C:\` to be printed out, instead of:

```
File parentDir = currentDir.getParentFile();
System.out.println("parent dir: " + parentDir.getName());
```

just call:

```
System.out.println("parent dir: " + currentDir.getParent());
```

or

```
File parentDir = currentDir.getParentFile();
System.out.println("parent dir: " + parentDir.getAbsolutePath());
```

which ALWAYS returns the String of the parent directory (or null if it doesn't exist)

On my machine it prints out:

```
--------------------------
parent dir: C:\
$Recycle.Bin         DIR
etc...
```